# error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ when using template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, g++, llvm

With this template in C++ that overloads operator<<

```
template<typename T> cEnvir& operator<<(const T& t) {out << t; return *this;}
```

I have this ambiguous error.

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ in ‘((cEnvir*)this)->cEnvir::out << t’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:169: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>

/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:173: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

...
```

The issues seems like that for typename T the compiler can't decide a match.
When I comment out `/* out << t; */`, the compilation works fine.

How can I resolve this issue? 
I use `gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)`.

Comment: Could we have more information. For example, where did you declare this template and what are the types of the different elements involved?

Comment: Post the whole error. We can't see what `T` is in this template instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

If you had this somewhere in your code,

```
long x = 1;
env << x;
```

where `env` is of type `Envir`, then the template ought to resolve unambiguously to call the correct streaming operator of `ostream`.

So I think the error arises somewhere outside the template definition itself.  Perhaps somewhere you have done something like this:

```
env << n;
```

where `env` is an `Envir`, and somehow, `n` is of a type that might be cast to `long` or to `unsigned long`, but it is not any type for which an `ostream::operator<<` function has been defined.  I am not sure what type that could be.